# Background process in web application in java

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, jms, ejb

I have list of invoices which has pdfs in it. Users can select n number of invoices and click download button. Immediately we will show the new window showing status as pending but in background all the pdf should be merged and if the merging is over, the status should be changed to Available.

How to achieve background process in web application after sending response and send again response after background process completes

Comment: I think you need asynchronous java programming. you can use CompletableFuture for this to run your task on second thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Web UI could send the request to the WebServer which immediately spawns an internal Thread and returns status pending. While the WebServer's thread is processing, your UI could be usable (unlocked) again.

Alternative 1: The Web UI could poll every 5 seconds or so (see HTML5 web worker) to check on the status of this processing by a request/replay and retrieve the final result when done.

Alternative 2: You could establish some form of 'push notification' from WebServer to WebUI to make it known to the UI once the processing is done. There are a couple of Push APIs out there (choose it depending on your backend/frontend language). Some simply implement a polling status check as described above for you..  Other's like WebSocket are more generic. Unfortunately there's no standard yet, but it's coming, I hope: https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/